# Meaning of expression: You may be 'something' but

Tags: grammar

What is the meaning of the expression:

> You may be *something* but...

For example:

> 1) You know what, Brian? You may be a dog but you're a pretty cool cat.
>
> 2) The lion may be the king of jungle, but the wolf never performs in the circus.
>
> 3) He may be poor, but he appears to be rich

Does *may be* with *but* work here as *despite the fact*? (but even if it does it only works for 1 & 3.)

> 1) Despite the fact that you're a dog, you're a pretty cool cat
>
> 3) Despite the fact that he's poor, he still looks rich

What could this expression possibly mean?

Comment: It can work for #2, also, with a bit of tweaking: _Despite the fact that the lion is king of the jungle, the wolf never performs in the circus._ Maybe you have to think about it a little more, but I think that sentence still works.

Answer (score -1):

You're definitely on the right way. "Even though" may help you understand the meaning too:

> The lion may be the king of jungle, but the wolf never performs in the circus. = Event though the lion is (supposedly) the king of jungle, the wolf never performs in the circus.
>
> Even though he is poor, he appears to be rich.

The sentence "*You know what, Brian? You may be a dog but you're a pretty cool cat*" is a bit tricky. I think I understand what the speaker means. But we might need more context here. Anyway, I'd interpret it like this:

> You know what, Brian? You may be a dog but you're a pretty cool cat. = You know what, Brain? You make a great dog but you're a pretty cool cat.

"Even though" or "despite the fact" which you have suggested work too, I think. But without more context, it's difficult to understand what makes the speaker say such a thing.